# youtube api does not play some vidoes in php

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

why i am getting error when i start playing videos or some videos from 'Vevo' or from other channels is not playing. its working fine in localhost by from network it gives error or not playing.

here is my youtube api complete code.

```
<?php


    $keyword = $movie_name .'movie songs';

    $keyword=preg_replace("/ /","+",$keyword);

    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q={$keyword}&type=video&key=AIzaSyBQCHmQUDDjQ99UKLF9OkBktAL4K88iUa8&maxResults=7");

    $searchResponse = json_decode($response,true);
    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
    $a = $searchResult['id']['videoId'];



    $b = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $searchResult['snippet']['title']);


    ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $a; ?>" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="videoItemContainer" onClick="playThis('<?php echo $a; ?>', '<?php echo $b; ?>')"> 


    <a href='#'>


       <img src="<?php echo $searchResult['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url']; ?>" style="height:200px; width:270px;" alt="Loading please wait...">

       <div style="font-size:14px; margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:60px;"> 

       <?php echo $searchResult['snippet']['title']; ?>

        </div>

    </a>

        </div>

        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: yes, what is the error? Double check your credentials for your API key in the Developer's Console https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: hi  @mpgn the error is "this video contains content from T-series. it is restricted from playback on certain sites" .

Comment: @johnh10  the error is "this video contains content from T-series. it is restricted from playback on certain sites"

Comment: Well there is your answer. Google search it. The copyright holder filed against the video using its content on certain sites.